# Why won't the Euro symbol display properly in this web page?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm using the following JSoup code to render this currency:

```
currencySpan.html("&euro;" + currencyFormat.format(estimatedValue));
```

However if you visit http://www.lastcalc.com/pmGgp1QR to see the output of this, it is displaying a '?' where the Euro symbol should be (before the 19.164 value).  I see this in both Chrome and Safari.

Why is this symbol not being displayed correctly?

*edit:* People are pointing out that this isn't a browser issue, rather the ? is being served up.  Basically I'm using JSoup's Element.html() to set the text (which includes the %euro;), and from there I use JSoup to render it to a string, which is returned to the browser (either directly when the page first loads, or as part of an AJAX JSON call if the page is edited).

This is the code that returns the document (resp is a HttpServletResponse):

```
resp.setContentType("text/html");
resp.getWriter().append(doc.toString());
```

*edit2:* I stuck a System.out.println(currencySpan); in there and sure enough, Java prints:

```
<span class=" currency">€19.164</span>
```

The strange thing is that JSoup appears to have converted & euro ; to the actual symbol, yet at some point it's not getting to the browser.

How do I ensure that the browser is treating what is returned by the servlet as UTF-8?

*edit3:* Fixed, I answered with the fix below.

Comment: The symbol on the web page as served to the browser is the question mark “?”. Since the encoding of the page is declared (in HTTP headers) as ISO-8859-1, it would not even be possible to include the euro sign as such, only as an entity referece like `&euro;` or as a character reference. Can you use UTF-8 encoding and write the actual euro sign “€” instead?

Comment: Hmm, in that case - why is JSoup converting &euro; to a '?'?  Surely it should serve that to the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that the browser wasn't interpreting the response as UTF-8, fixed with:

```
resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `&euro;` symbol is not making its way to the browser. If you view the source, it is showing a ? where I would expect to see the `&euro;` code in the html. if you look a this ( http://jsfiddle.net/gTLKq/ ) JSFiddle code, it clearly shows the euro symbol from the entity value you are using.

Therefore, JSoup is modifying your code. Are you cleaning the JSoup output, or doing anything else that may result in JSoup doing this?

Comment: I'm not doing anything, I'm basically just calling toString() on the JSoup Element and passing it to .html() in another element - and then returning the entire document using resp.getWriter().append(doc.toString());

Comment: hmmm, odd. JSoup is clearly not rendering what you are asking it to. Not sure why this would be the case. From what you have supplied, I can't see any obvious flaws.